# How to add spinner loader (NOT PROGRESS BAR) before webview loads a webpage in Android?

Tags: android, webview, dialog, spinner, loader

![enter image description here][1]

I have a webview inside Alert Dialog. How can i show loader spinner (NOT PROGRESS BAR) before webview loads and then hide once webpage is loaded ? Below is my code. Here i am not using any xml for webview, its dynamically generated simple webview :

```
     progress = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            progress.setMessage("Please wait......");
            progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progress.setIndeterminate(true);
            progress.show();

            WebView wv = new WebView(activity);
            //wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
              wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
              wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
              wv.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
              wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
              wv.setClickable(true);
              wv.setInitialScale(1);
              wv.loadUrl("https://www.yahoo.com");


            wv.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
                {
                    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    {
                        WebView webView = (WebView) v;

                        switch(keyCode)
                        {
                            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                                if(webView.canGoBack())
                                {
                                    webView.goBack();
                                    return true;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

            wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    // view.loadUrl(url);
                    // return true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "shouldOverrideUrlLoading");

                    String cleanUrl = url;
                    if (url.contains("?")) {
                        // remove the query string
                        cleanUrl = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));
                    }

                    if (cleanUrl.endsWith("pdf")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "application/pdf");
                        try {
                            Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(cleanUrl);
                            Intent intentUrl = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    uriUrl);
                            view.getContext().startActivity(intentUrl);
                            return true;

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "No PDF Viewer Installed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        view.loadUrl(url);
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (progress.isShowing()) {
                        progress.dismiss();
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageFinished");

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                        Bitmap favicon) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPageStarted");
                }
            });

            builder.setView(wv);
            builder.show();
            return false;
```

Comment: In my opinion you will have to add a progress bar to the layout where you are adding your webview.
And you can control its visibility using WebChromeClient's onProgressChanged() method.

Comment: Progress bar is not a spinner....I am looking for a circle loader...

Comment: Can you post the image of the desired spinner for more clarity?
You can create your own frame by frame animation for this purpose.

Comment: The thing on your image is a `ProgressBar` http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/progress.html

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
wv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
       if(progress==100){
           progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Haresh : Thanks, but I am looking for a loader spinner, not progress bar, does this code serves my purpose then ?

Comment: yes please try and let me know still have any problem.

Comment: Haresh : Please have a look at edited code. I tried something on my own. No actually what you suggested coz it requires xml to be defined for webview whereas mine is dynamically generated. In this case it didn't show me progress bar itself.

Comment: Debugging above code what i see is it is creating a progress dialog and dismissing as well, but display is not coming. Do u have any idea what could be reason ?